# Resizing partition from new hard drive

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, lvm

I just replaced my 500GB drive with a 1TB drive. I used a duper to copy the 500GB to the 1TB. Now I am trying to expand the partition (`/dev/sda3`) to take advantage of the new space. Here are (the most recent) commands I've tried. I'd like to do with without `gparted` because I only have SSH access to the machine.

```
tiny@ubuntu:~$ lsblk
NAME                 MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                    8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1                 8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2                 8:2    0   488M  0 part /boot
└─sda3                 8:3    0 929.4G  0 part 
  └─ubuntu--vg-root 252:0    0 464.8G  0 lvm  /
tiny@ubuntu:~$ sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root 
resize2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
The filesystem is already 121839616 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!

tiny@ubuntu:~$ sudo lvextend /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /dev/sda3
  No free extents on physical volume "/dev/sda3".
  No specified PVs have space available.
tiny@ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: sda3 already uses all of the space. I think you need to rebuild the LVM. An alternative -- split sda3 into 2 partitions. One 465G for vg-root. the other to be added to the LVM.

Comment: two ?'s. 1: how do i rebuild the LVM? I have the original 500GB disk so I can dupe it again and start over. 2: i used `parted` to expand `/dev/sda3` to use the `929.4G`, it was at `464.8G` before. What could i have done differently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what did it:

```
sudo pvresize /dev/sda3
sudo lvresize -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root
sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root
```

and here's the output:

```
tiny@ubuntu:~$ lsblk
NAME                 MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                    8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1                 8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2                 8:2    0   488M  0 part /boot
└─sda3                 8:3    0 929.4G  0 part 
  └─ubuntu--vg-root 252:0    0 464.8G  0 lvm  /
tiny@ubuntu:~$ df -h
Filesystem                    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                           95G     0   95G   0% /dev
tmpfs                          19G   11M   19G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  458G  239G  198G  55% /
tmpfs                          95G     0   95G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                         5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                          95G     0   95G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                     473M  120M  329M  27% /boot
/dev/sda1                     511M  3.4M  508M   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs                          19G     0   19G   0% /run/user/1000
tiny@ubuntu:~$ sudo pvresize /dev/sda3
  Physical volume "/dev/sda3" changed
  1 physical volume(s) resized / 0 physical volume(s) not resized
tiny@ubuntu:~$ sudo lvresize -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root
  Size of logical volume ubuntu-vg/root changed from 464.78 GiB (118984 extents) to 929.41 GiB (237929 extents).
  Logical volume root successfully resized.
tiny@ubuntu:~$ lsblk
NAME                 MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                    8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1                 8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2                 8:2    0   488M  0 part /boot
└─sda3                 8:3    0 929.4G  0 part 
  └─ubuntu--vg-root 252:0    0 929.4G  0 lvm  /
tiny@ubuntu:~$ df -h
Filesystem                    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                           95G     0   95G   0% /dev
tmpfs                          19G   11M   19G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  458G  239G  198G  55% /
tmpfs                          95G     0   95G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                         5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                          95G     0   95G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                     473M  120M  329M  27% /boot
/dev/sda1                     511M  3.4M  508M   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs                          19G     0   19G   0% /run/user/1000
tiny@ubuntu:~$ sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root
resize2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
Filesystem at /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root is mounted on /; on-line resizing required
old_desc_blocks = 30, new_desc_blocks = 59
The filesystem on /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root is now 243639296 (4k) blocks long.

tiny@ubuntu:~$ df -h
Filesystem                    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                           95G     0   95G   0% /dev
tmpfs                          19G   11M   19G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  915G  239G  637G  28% /
tmpfs                          95G     0   95G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                         5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                          95G     0   95G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                     473M  120M  329M  27% /boot
/dev/sda1                     511M  3.4M  508M   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs                          19G     0   19G   0% /run/user/1000
tiny@ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: ah the LVM could be resized. don't forget to accept your answer also.

Comment: how could i have checked that the LVM could be resized?

Comment: A google search probably could have produced the commands. LVM is Logical Volume Manager. what you have is a partition on the disk that is a container for a logical volume. The logical volume uses a set amount of space available to the containing partition. A short explanation of what you did .... first you resized the partition /sda3. then you resized the LV (logical volume) in that partition. then you extended the file system to  fill the volume (kind of like formating the new space).